# GRU model overfits

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have written a GRU model in order to predict power output. 
I have noticed though that after 5-6 epochs my val_loss starts to increase and doesn't stop after each epoch and it overfits pretty bad. 
I have tried a lot of things but nothing really works:

1. I've tried `relu`, `sigmoid` and `linear` activation functions.
2. I've started with 1 layer with different numbers of neurons and increased layers etc.
3. I've tried using `dropout` and L2 regularizer, but nothing really works, it either overfit after a few epochs or stays constant

My features are different physical paramters, like temperature, voltage, wind speed etc. and I'm trying to predict out put power. Am I using the wrong activation or optimizer, I really don't understand why it is overfitting.

Code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from google.colab import files
from tensorboardcolab import TensorBoardColab, TensorBoardColabCallback
tbc=TensorBoardColab() # Tensorboard
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.layers.recurrent import GRU
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras import regularizers
from keras.layers import Dropout





df10=pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Isolation Forest/IF 10 PERCENT.csv',index_col=None)
df2_10= pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/2019 Dataframe/2019 10minutes IF 10 PERCENT.csv',index_col=None)

X10_train= df10[['WindSpeed_mps','AmbTemp_DegC','RotorSpeed_rpm','RotorSpeedAve','NacelleOrientation_Deg','MeasuredYawError','Pitch_Deg','WindSpeed1','WindSpeed2','WindSpeed3','GeneratorTemperature_DegC','GearBoxTemperature_DegC']]
X10_train=X10_train.values

y10_train= df10['Power_kW']
y10_train=y10_train.values

X10_test= df2_10[['WindSpeed_mps','AmbTemp_DegC','RotorSpeed_rpm','RotorSpeedAve','NacelleOrientation_Deg','MeasuredYawError','Pitch_Deg','WindSpeed1','WindSpeed2','WindSpeed3','GeneratorTemperature_DegC','GearBoxTemperature_DegC']]
X10_test=X10_test.values

y10_test= df2_10['Power_kW']
y10_test=y10_test.values




# scaling values for the model


x_scale = MinMaxScaler()
y_scale = MinMaxScaler()

X10_train= x_scale.fit_transform(X10_train)
y10_train= y_scale.fit_transform(y10_train.reshape(-1,1))
X10_test=  x_scale.fit_transform(X10_test)
y10_test=  y_scale.fit_transform(y10_test.reshape(-1,1))


X10_train = X10_train.reshape((-1,1,12)) 
X10_test = X10_test.reshape((-1,1,12))



Early_Stop=EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5,mode='min',restore_best_weights=True)



# creating model using Keras
model10 = Sequential()
model10.add(GRU(units=256, return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001), input_shape=(1,12)))
model10.add(GRU(units=256, return_sequences=True,activation='linear'))
model10.add(GRU(units=128,activation='linear'))
#model10.add(GRU(units=256))
model10.add(Dense(units=1, activation='linear'))
model10.compile(loss=['mse'], optimizer='adam',metrics=['mse']) 
model10.summary() 


history10=model10.fit(X10_train, y10_train, batch_size=256, epochs=10,validation_split=0.10, verbose=1, callbacks=[TensorBoardColabCallback(tbc),Early_Stop])


score = model10.evaluate(X10_test, y10_test)
print('Score: {}'.format(score))



y10_predicted = model10.predict(X10_test)
y10_predicted = y_scale.inverse_transform(y10_predicted)

y10_test = y_scale.inverse_transform(y10_test)

plt.plot( y10_predicted, label='Predicted')
plt.plot( y10_test, label='Measurements')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('/content/drive/My Drive/Figures/Power Prediction 10 Percent.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: How good/bad is the accuracy?

Comment: I was told not to use accuracy in `metrics` as my dataframe is of everyone second of the year and is based on physical paramters which are constantly fluctuating.

Comment: "Why is my model overfitting" is not a programming question for Stack Overflow, but a machine learning question for Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange.com) or Data Science (datascience.stackexchage.com)

Comment: However, I'd also recommend to search both these sites (they're great!) for similar questions before asking... there's a lot of questions about overfitting there.

Answer (score 2):

One reason for `Overfitting` might be that you are using 3 `GRU Layers`.

You can start with 1 `GRU Layer` because stacking many `GRU` Layers not only leads to Overfitting but also is very expensive.

Ensure that you are cleaning the `Data` properly and that you are performing `Feature Engineering` (removing unnecessary columns, etc..) because the `Model` learns from undesired `Noise`.

If the `Model` is not `Overfitting` with 1 `Layer` and if there is scope of improvement in terms of `Accuracy` (or the respective `Metrics`), then we can add the 2nd `GRU Layer`.

We also need to add `Dropout` and `Recurrent_Dropout` in every `GRU Layer`, as shown below. They are very effective in mitigating Overfitting.

```
model10.add(GRU(units=256, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.3,
recurrent_dropout=0.4, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001), input_shape=(1,12)))

model10.add(GRU(units=256, return_sequences=True,activation='linear',
dropout=0.25, recurrent_dropout=0.3))

model10.add(GRU(units=128,activation='linear',
dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.35))
```

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!